# Writing in to different columns in a html table

Tags: python, html

I am trying to generate a html table from a python script.
this is my function to generate the table.

```
def generate_report(files, main_files, main):
    html_file = open("report.html", "w")
    html_file.write('<html>')
    html_file.write('<body>')
    html_file.write('<table border=1>')
    html_file.write('<tr>')
    html_file.write('<td>file Names</td>')
    for i in main:
        html_file.write('<th>%s</th>' % i)
    html_file.write('</tr>')
    for j in files:
        html_file.write('<tr>')
        html_file.write('<td>%s</td>' % j)
        html_file.write('<td style="background-color: %(color1)s;">%(value1)d</td>'
                    % {'value1': (count_in_lists(j, main_files)),
                       'color1': get_color(count_in_lists(j, files))})
        html_file.write('</tr>')
    html_file.write('</html>')
    html_file.write('</body>')
    html_file.write('</table>')

    html_file.close()
    webbrowser.open_new_tab('report.html')
```

and from another function i am calling this function to generate the table.below is the function

```
def report_main():
    for k in main_files:
        main_base_files = extract_base_files('path to a directory\\'+k+'')
        print(main_base_files)
        generate_report(base_files, main_base_files, main_files)
```

basically base_files,main_files and main_base_files are three lists that include some file names in a directory. count_in_lists() function compares base_files and main_base_files and counts the occurrences in base_files names in main_base_files list.
and  extract_base_files function just extract some file names from main files and storing it in a list
after running the script i am trying to generate a table with 5 columns but i am ending up with overwriting the same column.
how can i write to different columns when executing report_main() function?

Comment: Have you had a look at [pyquery](https://pypi.org/project/pyquery/)? That's jQuery for Python and should be much more convenient to use than hand-coding an HTML document.

Comment: thanks for pointing me out.i will have a look at that.for the moment i am trying to figure out how can i write to different columns in here.

Comment: Your logic fails because of the way you have implemented your for loop. You should iterate to a number equal to number of column  for each row of your table.

Comment: can you suggest me a good way to do this? i am stuck in this for quite a some time.

Comment: @Akalanka I think you need to set `tml_file = open("report.html", "w")` to `tml_file = open("report.html", "a")` write mode of opening a file rewrites all previous content as far as I know. OR else try iterating over `main_files` within generate report. This means opening and closing the file less.

Comment: @Dean no luck.still writing to the same column in the table.